# How to send push notification after analyzing api call return using firebase or any other cloud service?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to the device when some condition satisfies on the data returned by API call on the cloud. I can easily do this on the device but using API every minute, for hours,  might drain the battery and use a lot of internet. API returns JSON data. I have never used Firebase before but have used others (like Kumolos). Is there a way to do this or do I need to write code on the device?

I am coding for android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it on server side. For example you can use cron-job with PHP technology and window service or SignalR for .Net technology. For SignalR client side library is also available for android and ios

Comment: okay i will try it and let you know. Seems like a lot of work will take some time.